# mock python http requests for testing and development

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am using python "requests" and it works great, but now I want to be able to "mock" responses instead of touching the real servers.

I am doing this:

```
r = requests.get(self.url+'/somepath', params=payload)
```

In guzzlephp I could do this:

```
$mock = new MockHandler([
    new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'], 'mocked response')
]);

$handler = HandlerStack::create($mock);

$client = new Client(['handler' => $handler]);
```

is there something similar here in requests or in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use this library
https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html and do something like

```
>>> import requests
>>> import requests_mock

>>> with requests_mock.Mocker() as m:
...     m.get(self.url+'/somepath', text='mocked response')
...     requests.get(self.url+'/somepath').text
...
'mocked response'
```

Comment: yes found that package....

but I have my app that uses this object, so for mocking that there I'll need to change the code....